# How to identify a Clang QualType is a function pointer?

Tags: clang

I am trying to identify a function pointer connected to any expression. I am working in Clang code. Assume, I know the QualType of a value, and now want to know if the value is originally a function pointer, not any other. Like I want to distinguish between `void (*)()` and `int *`. Can anyone suggest what functionality (standard, not want to analyse the string) I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `QualType->isFunctionPointerType()`. The function `isFunctionPointerType` is actually part of Type class. QualType’s dereference operator returns a Type*, so we use `->` to call the function `isFunctionPointerType`.

*Credit: The question is originally answered by Sam McCall and Keane, Erich from cfe-dev mailing list*

Thanks